# Codeigniter combined AND OR condition not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select("item.*");
$this->db->from("items");
$this->db->where_not_in('item.ID', $Not);
$this->db->where_in('item_sub_category.Sub_category', $Sub_category);
$this->db->or_where_in('item_category.Category',$Category, NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->limit(4);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Output:

```
SELECT `item`.* 
FROM   `item` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_category` 
              ON `item_category`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_sub_category` 
              ON `item_sub_category`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
WHERE  `item`.`id` NOT IN( '12' ) 
       AND `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN( '65', '66', '67', '68' ) 
        OR `item_category`.`category` IN( '35', '36' ) 
LIMIT  4
```

Expected Output:

```
SELECT `item`.* 
FROM   `item` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_category` 
              ON `item_category`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_sub_category` 
              ON `item_sub_category`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
WHERE  `item`.`id` NOT IN( '12' ) 
       AND (`item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN( '65', '66', '67', '68' ) 
        OR `item_category`.`category` IN( '35', '36' )) 
LIMIT  4
```

Can anyone please tell me How can I achieve my expected output by using active record?

Comment: `where_in` and `or_where_in` will run both queries into one even you add another `where_in` it runs within one bracket.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add `join` in active records. like below.

```
$this->db->select("item.*");
$this->db->from("items");
$this->db->join("item_category","`item_category`.`item` = `item`.`id`","left");
$this->db->join("item_sub_category","`item_sub_category`.`item` = `item`.`id`","left");
$this->db->where_not_in('item.ID', $Not);
$this->db->where_in('item_sub_category.Sub_category', $Sub_category);
$this->db->or_where_in('item_category.Category',$Category, NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->limit(4);
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

// Try this ..

```
$array = array('item_sub_category.Sub_category' => $Sub_category, 'item_category.Category' => $Category);

    $this->db->select("item.*");
        $this->db->from("items");
        $this->db->join("item_category","`item_category`.`item` = `item`.`id`","left");
        $this->db->join("item_sub_category","`item_sub_category`.`item` = `item`.`id`","left");
        $this->db->where_not_in('item.ID', $Not);
        $this->db->where_in($array);
        $this->db->limit(4);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't put in your whole query - but if its the where condition which concerns you - you can do the following:

```
$this->db
    ->select("item.*")
    ->from("item")
    ->where_not_in('item.ID', $Not)
    ->group_start()
        ->where_in('item_sub_category.Sub_category', $Sub_category)
        ->or_where_in('item_category.Category',$Category, NULL, FALSE)
    ->group_end()
    ->limit(4);

echo $this->db->get_compiled_select();
```